# File upload via HTTPS using libcurl in C

Tags: c, curl, file-upload

I am writing a file upload via HTTPS using the curl library in C.
The server side is running a small web application using the ulfius framework.

My code looks like this (shorted):

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
void * buffer = NULL;
long length;
FILE *fd;

fd = fopen(filePath, "rb");
if (fd) {
  fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
  length = ftell(fd);
  fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
  buffer = malloc(length * sizeof (void));
  if (buffer) {
      fread(buffer, 1, length, fd);
  }
  fclose(fd);
}

curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl) {
  struct curl_slist *chunk = NULL;
  chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Accept: */*");
  chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "X-IsReplication: 1");

  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://192.168.1.6:8080/upload/test.txt/");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, chunk);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, length);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, buffer);

  res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
  if (res != CURLE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
  } else {
    printf("Success!\n");
  }

  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

The error message from curl_easy_strerror() is: "Failure when receiving data from the peer".
If I do a capture with Wireshark, I see some encrypted TCP packets, but no TLS packets.
The "Client Hello" and "Server Hello" messages are also missing.

Let's pretend the server side is working correctly, because if I switch to HTTP (server + client) everything works fine.
Is there something missing in the curl part of my code?
It seems that there is no SSL/TLS Handshake.

Comment: I have found a bug on the server side. The code above is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and the TLS/SSL connection works fine. Try the following:

- Check your server TLS/SSL configuration with an [online tool](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/).
- If your server implements it correctly, then try to force the preferred TLS/SSL with the following line of code: `curl_easy_setopt(CURL *handle, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, long version);`

More documentation about this command [here](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSLVERSION.html).